# Calling a generic method with some known type arguments

Tags: c#, list, generics, methods

I'm trying to call a generic but don't know how this should work. I looked around the internet and could not find a solution whichmatches my case.

I got following method:

```
public void method<T>(string name, string sheet, List<List<T>> xList, List<List<T>> yList)
```

Now I want to simply invoke this method. When I do so I get an error and it tells me that I have to specify the type arguments. When I specify them then it tells me that a "one-type-argument" is needed. What am I doing wrong here? I read that this should be done by reflection or something else but can't get it to work.

I tried to invoke the method with:

```
method<string, string, List<List<DateTime>>, List<List<Double>>>(name, sheet, xList, yList)
```

but this does not work!

Comment: Could you post an example and the complete error ?

Comment: How are you invoking the medthod.  Can you edit your post to show this?

Comment: Ok I edited my post.

Comment: `method<DateTime>(name,sheet,xList,yList)` is how you would invoke it.  You can't have xList be a `List<List<DateTime>>` and yList be a `List<List<Double>>` since both are defined a `<T>`.

Comment: Oh ok so it is not possible to pass two Lists of different types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
public void method<T1, T2>(string name, string sheet, List<List<T1>> xList, List<List<T2>> yList)
```

instead of

```
public void method<T>(string name, string sheet, List<List<T>> xList, List<List<T>> yList)
```

Comment: And invoked like `method<DateTime,Double>(name,sheet,xList,yList)`

Comment: Yes thats it! Thank you very much. Didn't know that it would be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

you only have 1 generic parameter.  If T is a string then you would invoke your method like

```
method<string>(name,sheet,xList,yList);
```

if T is a DateTime then you would invoke like

```
method<DateTime>(name,sheet,xList,yList);
```

Or if you need 2 generic Parameters then you would do

```
method<T,U>(string name,string sheet,List<List<T>> xList, List<List<U>> xList);
```

And invoke like

```
  method<DateTime,Double>(name,sheet,xList,yList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic type on your xlist and ylist must be the same. For example this works.

```
void Main() {
    var foo = new List<List<Foo>>();
    var foo2 = new List<List<Foo>>();
    method("sdf", "sdf", foo, foo2);
}

class Foo{}
```

But in order to pass two lists of different types you would have to change your method signature to `public void method<T,U>(string name, string sheet, List<List<T>> xList, List<List<U>> yList)`. Then something like this...

```
void Main() {
    var foo = new List<List<Foo>>();
    var bar = new List<List<Bar>>();
    method("sdf", "sdf", foo, bar);
}

class Foo{}
class Bar{}
```

Would be possible.